# C++ If statement to determine if given value is a number

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-overloading

I'm programming a simple program that generates a report of some data into the file. The final file so far looks like this:

```
    Date: Mon Oct 09 16:33:09 2017

LENOVO-KOMPUTER                                                                           
+------+----------+-------+------+
|  ID  |   name   | temp. | poj. |
+------+----------+-------+------+
|000000|hejka     |    1.5|     0|
|000001|naklejka  |   31.8|     1|
|000002|dupa      |    0.0|     2|
|000003|proba     |    0.0|     3|
|000004|cos       |    0.0|     4|
|000005|nic       |    0.0|     5|
|000006|polewamy  |    0.0|     6|
|000007|sie       |    0.0|     7|
|000008|szampanem |    0.0|     8|
|000009|ojojoj    |    0.0|     9|
+------+----------+-------+------+
|      |          |       |      |
+------+----------+-------+------+
```

Each line is a separate structure, that looks like this:

```
struct Data{
    int id;
    char name[10];
    double temp;
    double poj;
```

In the blank spaces at the bottom I have to sum up the whole column above. I need to use overloaded += operator to sum a column up (one has to work for all of them), but second one needs to stay clean, cause there is only text there (it needs to stay clear AFTER using that += operator thing on it).

**How do I determine whether I can sum up the values (cause they're numbers) or I can't (cause it's text)?** I think it needs to be some kind of "if statement" at the beginning but I can't find anything that'd work. I'd like it to look like this:

```
if(the given value is a number){
*add up all the numbers and put the result in a right spot*
}
else{
*it's not a number so i can't do anything, leave the spot (where the result should be) blank*
}
```

Comment: If you are generating the report how would you *not* know which elements are numbers? What does your data look like?

Comment: How is your data structured in your program?

Comment: @Galik yes, but the thing is, I need to use this += operator on each column individually and that's the problem. When it's used on the second column it needs to be like "Oh, there's no numbers here, mission aborted".

Comment: What are the data types?  How are you organizing your data?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews each line is a structure that contains int, string and 2x double

Comment: You need to discuss with the instructor, as to what the summary for the text column should be.  I'm either going with blank or "N/A" (Not Appropriate).

Comment: Then add up the *ints* and the *doubles*, but not the *strings*?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use operator overloading? Or it's just for the sake of use it?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it just needs to stay blank.

Comment: @Galik no, because I have to use the overloaded operator on a string too and it has to just leave it blank.

Comment: @Neb Well it's sort of my home task. I think it's just so we get used to it, so it's pushed in everywhere.

Comment: Are you asking how to overload the `+=` operator to add objects of your struct?

Comment: `mystruct operator+=(mystruct const& other) { /* what goes here? */ }`?

Comment: @Galik no, I know how to do it in general, just not in this exact case because here is how it has to work:1. I am writing one overloaded operator. 2.I use it four times, for each column individually. 3. 1st, 3rd and 4th columns sum up and the value goes where it should, but 2nd one stays blank. That's because there's text there and there should be some if - statement in the beginning of the overloaded operator 'function' that determines if it's a number or not. That's what I'm asking for - how this if statement should look like.

Comment: Without seeing your code and data structures it is hard to see what you are asking for. Can you post what you have so far (just the relevant bits)?

Comment: @Galik I edited my question

Comment: What does "the given value" look like? Is it a string? What does it contain?

Comment: @Galik the value for first column is always an int, then it's a string and then the last two columns are double type.

Comment: @Ron I have it in the program, just assigned by me in the main function, nothing fancy, it just is in the program.

Comment: @Ania: The first column is an ID, that should not be summed either. I firmly believe you have misunderstood exactly what it is you need to do here.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for general solution where it is not good solution since you know which columns have numbers, which do not.

But as an exercise in relatively advanced C++ this can be done:

```
    #include <type_traits>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <vector>
    #include <optional>
    #include <iostream>

    template <typename T>
    std::optional<std::string> sum_only_numbers(const std::vector<T>& values) {
        if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>){
            const auto sum = std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), T{0});
            return std::to_string(sum);  
        }
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    int main() {
        std::cout << *sum_only_numbers(std::vector<float>{1.1,2.2}) << std::endl;
        std::cout << *sum_only_numbers(std::vector<int>{11,22}) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << sum_only_numbers(std::vector<std::string>{"will", "be", "ignored"}).has_value() 
                  << std::endl;    
    }
```

Comment: "Is_arithmetic" is an enough of an answer. Thank you so much, that's what I needed.

Comment: @Ania This will generate a seperate function for each datatype. What you need is probaply just a function that take two objects of type `struct Data` and adds them together, as @Galik wrote.

Comment: @SisterFister nobody seemed to really understand what I needed and what it was just this short thing called "is_arithmetic" and that's it. I know how to write all the rest, just didn't know about the name of that thing.

Comment: I am happy that you find my answer helpful but like I said it is nontrivial C++, in particular is_arithmetic and other is_something from type_traits operates on types, not values, and that is a bit of an advanced C++. So if you or anybody else reading this answer is a beginner they may want to use simpler logic to implement this functionality.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl okay I looked more into it and turns out it's not exactly what I was looking for. Isn't there something that'll check it? I can bet I saw something like that last year when I was just a beginner, there was something checking whether the given letter is big or not and so on.

Comment: @Ania As said, this works by simply creating a separate function for each type. I'll post some code to show how the version Galik mentioned.

Comment: @SisterFister i just found something called 'isalpha()' and it seems to be working.

Comment: @Ania This probaply only seems to work, because `isalpha` only checks if a number is an alphabetic character based on the ascii code.

Comment: Like I said there is a difference between checking a value of variable and type of variable. For example you can ask yourself if string a number type(int, long, float double)? It is not. This is a question about types. Another example is asking if string is longer than 10 charachters? This is a question about value. Be sure you are not confusing the two. My solution asks questions about types, while isalpha asks questions about values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code which overloads the +=  and the + operator to add the rows:

```
struct Data {
    int id;
    char name[10];
    double temp;
    double poj;
}

struct DataSum { // this class/struct contains the result of an addition of two rows (this means that name and id are omitted here)
    double temp;
    double poj;

    DataSum() : temp(0), poj(0) {} // default constructor

    DataSum (const Data& data) : temp(data.temp), poj(data.poj) {} // constructor which converts a Data object to a DataSum object

    DataSum operator+= (const DataSum& data) { // overloaded += operator
        temp += data.temp;
        poj += data.poj;
        return *this;
    }
};

DataSum operator+ (DataSum left, const DataSum& right) { // overloaded + operator
    return left += right;
}

int main (void) {
    struct Data table[100]; // array of 100 table rows (needs to be initialized)
    struct DatSum result_row; // final row of the table which needs to be calculated

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { // loop through all the rows
        result_row += table[i]; // add one row at a time to the result, note that table[i] will be implicitly converted to a DataSum object with the converting constructor before it will be added to result_row
    }

    // print the table and the result_row
}
```

I did not run this code, so maybe there are some typos/bugs in it...

Comment: A little type safety never hurts: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1083c280287f8c97

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks, I'll add it to the answer if you don't mind. I'm mostly write C code after all, so I would have to look up the overloading syntax :D

Comment: @MooingDuck added your code, hope I've got everything right...